# Why is there a difference between binascii.b2a_base64() and base64.b64encode()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to understand some divergent behavior I'm seeing with the following two functions:

```
def hex_to_64(string):
    hex_string = binascii.a2b_hex(string)
    return binascii.b2a_base64(hex_string)

def hex_to_64_2(string):
    hex_string = binascii.a2b_hex(string)
    return base64.b64encode(hex_string)
```

If I pass in a hex string to the former, I get it back with a newline at the end, and the latter without. Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing special, the implementators decided to do it that way. It is documented at [binascii module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_base64).

> Convert binary data to a line of ASCII characters in base64 coding. The return value is the converted line, including a newline char. The length of data should be at most 57 to adhere to the base64 standard.

If you don't feel comfortable with that just `right strip` it:

```
hex_to_64('aa').rstrip('\n')
>>>'qg=='
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just take off the last character (in case the original text ends in a newline)?

Comment: Whatever you feel comfortable with :) You can try `hex_to_64('aa')[:-1]` as well.